# Show data when Google Maps marker is clicked in markercluster

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I am trying to work out how to show custom data when a Google Maps markerclusterer marker is clicked but can't find this documented anywhere.

My markerclusterer code looks like this but my attempt at capturing the click event on a marker is not working:

```
var markerClusterer = null;
var map = null;
var imageUrl = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=mm&chs=24x32&' +
  'chco=FFFFFF,008CFF,000000&ext=.png';
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function refreshMap() {
    if (markerClusterer) {
      markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
    }
    var markers = [];
    var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(imageUrl,
      new google.maps.Size(24, 32));
      /*
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.photos[i].latitude,
          data.photos[i].longitude)
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: latLng,
       icon: markerImage
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }
    */
    for (var i = 0; i < numItemsToShow; ++i) {
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(itemsToShow[i].lat, itemsToShow[i].long);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: latLng,
       icon: markerImage
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }
    var zoom = parseInt(document.getElementById('zoom').value, 10);
    var size = parseInt(document.getElementById('size').value, 10);
    var style = parseInt(document.getElementById('style').value, 10);
    zoom = zoom == -1 ? null : zoom;
    size = size == -1 ? null : size;
    style = style == -1 ? null: style;


    markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
      maxZoom: zoom,
      gridSize: size,
      styles: styles[style]
    });
}

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.91, 116.38),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        //styles: [{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#444444"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.land_parcel","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"}]},{"featureType":"landscape.natural","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#052366"},{"saturation":"-70"},{"lightness":"85"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":"-100"},{"lightness":"0"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"lightness":"-53"},{"weight":"1.00"},{"gamma":"0.98"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"},{"lightness":"0"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"hue":"#3dff00"},{"saturation":"-100"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":45},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"saturation":"-18"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#57677a"},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"lightness":"40"}]}]
        styles: [{"featureType":"water","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#b5cbe4"}]},
            {"featureType":"landscape","stylers":[{"color":"#efefef"}]},
            {"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#83a5b0"}]},
            {"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#bdcdd3"}]},
            {"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},
            {"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#e3eed3"}]},
            {"featureType":"administrative","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":33}]},
            {"featureType":"road"},
            {"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":20}]},{},
            {"featureType":"road","stylers":[{"lightness":20}]}]
    });
    var refresh = document.getElementById('refresh');
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(refresh, 'click', refreshMap);
    var clear = document.getElementById('clear');
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(clear, 'click', clearClusters);

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerClusterer, 'click', function () {
      // do something with this marker ...
      this.setTitle('I am clicked');
    });

    refreshMap();
}

function clearClusters(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the marker click event would work any differently if the marker is being managed by a marker clusterer?  Or are you asking about the click event on the clusters?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (the map styles are certainly not relevant, nor is the commented out code).

Comment: Your code works for me (the click event changes the title on the marker clusters to "I am clicked").  Why do you believe it isn't working?

Comment: I mentioned markerclusterer just in case it was significant. It is better to provide too much rather than too little information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me (it opens an infowindow when you mouseover the cluster icon, if you click on the cluster icon, the default behavior is to zoom to the cluster bounds, which makes it hard to see the change of the tooltip/title on the cluster icon):

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
google.maps.event.addListener(markerClusterer, 'mouseover', function (cluster) {
  // do something with this cluster ...
  infoWindow.setContent("Mouseover<br>"+cluster.getCenter().toUrlValue());
  infoWindow.setPosition(cluster.getCenter());
  infoWindow.open(map);
});
```